# How to insert handlebars template to external Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I want to separate the javascript file in a handlebars file,but unfortunately it wont work.

Attempt :

index.handlebars :

```
<script src = "javascript/detail.js"></script>
```

detail.js

```
{ { #each restaurants } }
var marker = L.marker([{{ this.restaurant.location.latitude }}, { { this.restaurant.location.longitude } }]).addTo(mymap);
{{/each}}
```

I always get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

When I put the code inside detail.js to the bottom of index.handlebars,it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Basically I just copy paste the script into a partial handlebars file, and then just write the partial tag